# Get <p> content using selenium Webdriver

Tags: node.js, selenium-webdriver

I have the following `<p>` tag wrapped in `<div>` tag using selenium Webdriver and I would like to get the `<p>` tag content using node.js

```
<div id="guideContainer-rootPanel-HouseholdContact-guidetextbox___guideFieldShortDescription" class="guideFieldDescription short" style="null;display:none">
    <p>Enter the first name of the contact person.</p>
</div>
```

Comment: What exactly do you mean by `tag wrapped in tag`? Update the question with your code trials and error stack trace

Comment: Thank you for your reply Debanjan, I added a code snippet.

Comment: In the future, please take a minute to review your question after it's posted. A lot of the relevant info was not showing up because you used HTML tags and didn't mark them as code or indent them properly making the question hard to understand.

Comment: That `DIV` is hidden so you won't be able to use typical methods to get the text since Selenium doesn't interact with hidden elements by design. You will need to use JavaScript to extract the text or perform whatever action on the page that makes those elements visible.